# Using mariadb4j and vertx.io unit test together

Tags: java, junit, mariadb, vert.x

I'm experimenting with `mariadb4j`, I'm trying to use it in my `VertxUnit` tests. `mariadb4j` looks easy but I'm facing some strange behavior. In my `@BeforeAll` method I set up a `mariadb4j` instance, create a database and fill it with tables. Then on each test I truncate the table of interest and fill it with precondition rows. Precondition rows are expressed in some .sql resource, so, in each test, I simply run the `db.source("precondition_rows_about_this_test.sql", "root", "", "dbstuff");` command. But test hangs showing this message in the log:

```
2018-03-25 16:48:07 INFO  ManagedProcess:144 - Starting Program [C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\MariaDB4j\base\bin\mysql.exe, -uroot, -p, -Ddbstuff, --port=52733] (in working directory C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\MariaDB4j\base)
2018-03-25 16:48:07 INFO  ManagedProcess:383 - Thread is now going to wait for this process to terminate itself: Program [C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\MariaDB4j\base\bin\mysql.exe, -uroot, -p, -Ddbstuff, --port=52733] (in working directory C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\MariaDB4j\base)
```

Here is my test:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initAll() throws Exception {
  DBConfigurationBuilder dbConfBuilder = DBConfigurationBuilder.newBuilder();
  dbConfBuilder.setPort(0);
  dbConf = dbConfBuilder.build();
  db = DB.newEmbeddedDB(dbConf);
  db.start();
  db.createDB("dbstuff");
  db.source("dbstuff.sql", "root", null, "dbstuff");
}

@Before
public void initTest(TestContext ctx) throws Exception {
  db.run("use dbstuff; truncate table stuff");
  query = new JsonObject();
  VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions();
  vertxOptions.setMaxEventLoopExecuteTime(Long.MAX_VALUE);
  vertx = new VertxFactoryImpl().vertx(vertxOptions);

  DeploymentOptions dbDeploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions();
  dbDeploymentOptions.setConfig(new JsonObject());
  dbDeploymentOptions.getConfig().put("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:" + dbConf.getPort() + "/dbstuff");
  dbDeploymentOptions.getConfig().put("user", "root");
  dbDeploymentOptions.getConfig().put("password", "");

  vertx.deployVerticle(RecipesPlanner.class, dbDeploymentOptions, ctx.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@Test
public void recipePlannerComputeRecipePlanAbout10AllQueryPlanAndThereIsOnly1RecipeInDb(TestContext ctx)
    throws Exception {
  Async async = ctx.async();
  db.source("1goodstuff.sql", "root", "", "dbstuff");
  vertx.eventBus().send("givestuff", query, new DeliveryOptions().addHeader("action", "get-stuff"),
    msg -> {
        if (msg.failed())
          log.error(msg.cause());
        ctx.assertTrue(msg.succeeded());
        log.info(msg.result().body().toString());
        JsonArray stuff = new JsonArray(msg.result().body().toString());
        ctx.assertEquals(10, stuf.size());
        async.complete();
    });
}
```

Well, in the `@Test` method, test hangs on the `db.source` line. Of course I'm sure .sql files are correct. I am using `vertx.io 3.5.1` and `mariadb4j 2.2.3`. What am I missing?

Comment: May be https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j/issues/89

Comment: @zella Maybe near. I tried to dump hanging thread by jstack but no luck: `Unable to attach to 32-bit process running under WOW64` and now I run out of ideas..